# Finding partial derivatives of z via spatial convolution

Tags: matlab, convolution, derivative

I've been tasked with finding the partial derivatives `dz/dx` and `dz/dy` of a function `z` via spatial convolution in MATLAB. As far as I'm aware, spatial convolution is just the product of a spatial domain, and some form of filter. I'm assuming the filter in this case is the partial derivation? What would be the best approach for this, as I already have the surface calculated?

```
%values of z. 
x = -9:0.2:9;
y = -8:0.2:8;
z = comp_z(x,y)
colormap('hot') %as specified
zfinal=z';
surf(x,y,zfinal)
```

Comment: We don't have `comp_z`, is it a special function or something?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like homework, so I will just point you to the right direction but not give you code.

A central differences derivative of dz/dx on point `z_i` is defined as `dz_i/dx=(z_{i-1}+z_{i+1})/2`

If `z` is a matrix, and you can apply `[-0.5 0 0.5]` to the value `z_i`, then you would obtain the same equation for `dz_i/dx`. If you apply this to all elements (or spacially convolve the filter over the image) you'd obtain this value for all elements.

Same logic can be obtained for `dz_i/dy`.